# Certificate for gcp loadbalancer not validating

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to setup a classic load balancer to for my website. The code/container is running on Cloud Run and works fine.

The http route works fine through the load balancer, however the ssl certificate continues to give FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE. Clearly, I am missing something! I have deployed the LB using a shell script and have attached the script below. I have removed the domain name from the certificate.

```
SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME='ea-ssl2'
DOMAIN='xxxxx.co.uk'
TARGET_HTTP_PROXY_NAME='ea-http-proxy2'
TARGET_HTTPS_PROXY_NAME='ea-https-proxy2'
URL_MAP_NAME='ea-url-map2'
EXTERNAL_IP='ea-external-ip'
SERVERLESS_NEG_NAME='ea-serverless2-neg'
CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME='ea-website'
BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME='ea-backend-service'
REGION=europe-west2
HTTP_FORWARDING_RULE_NAME='ea-http-forwarding-rule'
HTTPS_FORWARDING_RULE_NAME='ea-https-forwarding-rule'

echo '**** Firstly, create an External IP \n\n'

#gcloud compute addresses create $EXTERNAL_IP \
#    --network-tier=PREMIUM \
#    --ip-version=IPV4 \
#    --global

gcloud compute addresses describe $EXTERNAL_IP \
    --format="get(address)" \
    --global


echo "\n\n*** Now Create the Network Endpoint Group (NEG) ***\n\n"

gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups create $SERVERLESS_NEG_NAME \
   --region=$REGION \
   --network-endpoint-type=serverless  \
   --cloud-run-service=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME


echo '\n\n*** Create the Backend Service ***\n\n'

gcloud compute backend-services create $BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME \
  --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
  --global

echo '*** Add the NEG to the Backend Service ***\n\n'

gcloud compute backend-services add-backend $BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME \
   --global \
   --network-endpoint-group=$SERVERLESS_NEG_NAME \
   --network-endpoint-group-region=$REGION


echo '*** Now Create the URL MAP ***\n\n'

gcloud compute url-maps create $URL_MAP_NAME \
   --default-service $BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME

gcloud compute target-http-proxies create $TARGET_HTTP_PROXY_NAME \
   --url-map=$URL_MAP_NAME


echo "\n\n*** Now Create the SSL Certificate ***\n\n"
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create $SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME \
   --domains $DOMAIN

echo '\n\n**** Create Target Proxy'
echo ' --- TargetProxy Name',$TARGET_HTTPS_PROXY_NAME
echo ' --- Certificate Name',$SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME

gcloud compute target-https-proxies create $TARGET_HTTPS_PROXY_NAME \
  --ssl-certificates=$SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME \
  --url-map=$URL_MAP_NAME


echo '\n************************************************************'
echo '***********  Add Forwarding Rules                ***********'
echo '************************************************************'
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create $HTTP_FORWARDING_RULE_NAME \
   --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
   --network-tier=PREMIUM \
   --address='ea-http-ip' \
   --target-http-proxy=$TARGET_HTTP_PROXY_NAME \
   --global \
   --ports=80

echo "Now Add 443 Target Proxy"
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create $HTTPS_FORWARDING_RULE_NAME \
    --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
    --network-tier=PREMIUM \
    --address=$EXTERNAL_IP \
    --target-https-proxy=$TARGET_HTTPS_PROXY_NAME \
    --global \
    --ports=443
```

Comment: Is the domain a verified domain for the credentials used by your script? Was the SSL certificate actually created? Your post does not show the DNS changes that you made. Note: your script does no error checking. You should validate the success or failure of each command.

Answer (score 1):

- Update the DNS A records to point to the load balancer's IP address
- Run a dig EXAMPLE.com in order to check whether lb ip is properly provisioned
- gcloud compute ssl-certificates describe CERTIFICATE_NAME 
  --format="get(managed.domainStatus)" #Sometimes propagation across the internet takes up to 72 hours worldwide, although it typically takes a few hours.
- Read [Troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting)
- From experience, create DNS records then create LB
- [Other users experiencing similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886750/google-managed-ssl-certificate-stuck-on-failed-not-visible?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @dany L's answer, I would suggest to just recreate the current SSL certificate after making sure that your A record is pointed to the correct Load Balancer's Frontend IP address, if it has been more than 60 minutes since it started trying to provision.

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#replace-ssl):

> Provisioning a Google-managed certificate might take up to `60 minutes` from the moment your DNS and load balancer configuration changes have propagated across the internet. If you have updated your DNS configuration recently, it can take a significant amount of time for the changes to fully propagate. Sometimes propagation takes up to 72 hours worldwide, although it typically takes a few hours. For more information on DNS propagation.

---

These tools are also helpful in checking the status of both the SSL certificate and the DNS:

- [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)
- [Dig Tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/)